# Show databases command doesn't show my databases in MAMP in OS X

Tags: mysql, mamp-pro

When I connect with `/applications/mamp/library/bin/mysql -u root -p` I enter perfectly to MySQL prompt, but the `show databases` command does not show any database. However, in phpMyadmin I see all my databases.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you end the query with `;`?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're connecting to the correct port.

Comment: MAMP PRO uses the port 8889 but when I execute the command I don't say what port to use but I open the connection after type the correct password and I get the mysql prompt so I assume that I using the correct por no?

Comment: It looks like chrki gave you an answer that workd. However, for others who might run into this situation, the fact that you got to a mysql prompt does not necessarily mean that you've reached MAMP's version of MySQL. If you already have MySQL running on your computer under port 3306, which is MySQL's default port, and if your MySQL password is the same for both your computer's MySQL and MAMP's MySQL, then, unless you specify the port that MAMP's MySQL is running under, you will have logged into your computer's MySQL instead. If that happens you won't see your MAMP databases.